# GNU Make can never find perl?

Tags: perl, makefile, compilation, arm, gnu-make

I sometimes get this error when compiling a program:

```
make[1]: /usr/bin/perl: Command not found
make[1]: *** [links] Error 127
```

This happens with any program that requires perl to compile, such as openssl and automake. However:

```
sh-2.05b# perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.0 DEVEL34342 built for arm-linux-thread-multi
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

sh-2.05b# /usr/bin/perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.0 DEVEL34342 built for arm-linux-thread-multi
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)
```

I definitely have perl installed. What's going on?

Comment: What kind of system did you develop the script on (and the make-file)?  Did the actual files come from a Windows system originally?

Comment: Well, that eliminates one possibility (that you have an invisible ^M at the end of your /usr/bin/perl definition because of a file being imported from a different OS without conversion).

Comment: This is strange. Could you show us the makefile rule? (Note that it's being called recursively.)

Comment: My first guess would be that Perl is installed somewhere other than /usr/bin.  Try typing 'which perl' or 'type perl' on the command line to find out where Perl is installed.

Comment: Well, I worked around by invoking make directly. For some reason it wouldn't find perl if invoked by another script.

Comment: Simplest way to solve this would be to post your Makefile and also post the relevant bits of the script which is invoking it.  The machine you're testing it on and the machine the script is running it on... they are the same, right?  Also, could you have multiple versions of make?

Comment: It's sometimes a good idea to use something like "/usr/bin/env perl" rather than assuming that perl is installed in /usr/bin. This is especially the case for shell scripts, but it's probably right for make too.

Answer (score 1):

If this is reproducible, run the `make` command with `strace -f`, to see unambiguously which command is attempting (and failing) to exec.

I can recall from my own experience the following two situations in which an `exec`-family might fail on Linux with `ENOENT` despite that the command is actually there:

1. The `.interp` referred to by the binary isn't present (example: the LSB-compatible binary refers to `/lib/ld-lsb.so.3` instead of the usual `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, and LSB compatibility packages haven't been installed on the Linux machine).  Seems unlikely in your scenario :)
2. Some kernel-level non-standard security mechanism is in place which is blocking execution of the binary - especially on locked-down embedded devices.  One would think `EACCES` would be the more logical errno in this case, but maybe `ENOENT` is used to prevent leaking information about the existence of binaries to unprivileged processes.